# What do the OpenGL extensions do?

Tags: opengl, gpu

I have come across a lot of these for GPU Programming in [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/registry/#arbextspecs). How do they work. A working example from the hyperlink (OpenGL registry) would help. How can one write such extensions?

Comment: i think you should use google for questions like this.

Comment: I think, i made it clear now.

Answer (score 2):

> How do they work.

OpenGL extensions "work" by you reading the extension specification, understanding what the new functions/enumerators/GLSL additions do. Then you use an appropriate [OpenGL loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) to check whether the extension is available. If it is, you can use those functions/enumerators/GLSL additions in your program *on that OpenGL implementation*.

If it's an extension that interacts with GLSL, then you have to do a bit more work. Your shader has to be written to require the extension (and thus will fail to compile if the extension isn't available). It must [explicitly state](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Core_Language#Extensions) which extensions it uses.

> A working example from the hyperlink (OpenGL registry) would help.

No. There are plenty of [OpenGL loading libraries](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) that will load the available extensions and provide enumerators and such. Use one of them.

> How can one write such extensions?

You don't. At least, not a *working* one.

OpenGL is nothing more than a specification, a PDF file that you can read. An *implementation* of OpenGL is what someone writes when they want people to use OpenGL with their hardware.

OpenGL extensions are much like OpenGL itself. Nothing more than a [set of documents](http://www.opengl.org/registry/#arbextspecs). An implementation may *expose* some set of extensions, but whether they do or not is up to the writers of that implementation. Not the *users* of it.

You can write an OpenGL extension, using the format available for doing so. But it would be just another document. But odds are *very* good nobody will implement it. And thus, it'll just be a text file on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenGL extensions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extensions):

> OpenGL extensions are a means for OpenGL implementations to provide
>   new or expanded functionality that the core of OpenGL does not
>   provide. Using extensions should not be looked on as something to be
>   avoided; it should be accepted as standard practice for the OpenGL
>   user.
>
> Some extensions expose features that only one particular hardware
>   vendor exposes, but many extensions are implemented by multiple
>   implementations. There is a mechanism for determining which extensions
>   are available from a particular implementation.

Comment: That explains first part of my question. Can you explain the next 2 parts?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are making your own GPU hardware or writing a software OpenGL implementation, you will not be writing your own OpenGL extensions.  The extension is really just a specification for hardware vendors to implement at will.

Comment: So, if i found that a GPU can have a capability of delivering something better, i can write an extension for that? Is that device specific or architecture specific(GPU)?

Comment: Doubtful.  GPU manufacturers are pretty tight-lipped about their architectures, so it would be difficult to hack your own driver code for them.

Comment: Well, you _can_ always write your own extension, since that is merely a specification using a particular template. It is however highly doubtful that Khronos will host your extension on the OpenGL site or that even IHVs will support it... Besides, not all extensions need device-specific features, take for example buffer objects or geometry shaders.

Comment: @Damon Good point. The extension is just a spec for the drivers/hardware to implement.

Answer (score 1):

> How do they work.

The OpenGL library you find on modern operating systems covers only a very basic version of OpenGL. Usually something in the range between OpenGL-1.1 to OpenGL-1.5. Any modern feature that a OpenGL driver wants to expose to user applications are provided through the *extension mechanism*.

The extension mechanism is a method for a GPU's driver to expose functionality that is newer or more advanced, than what the standard system OpenGL interface library provides.

*(Update due to Nicol Bolas comment):* It is important to understand, that there is a difference between a **extension** and the extension **mechanism**. The extension mechanism are the functions `{glX,wgl,…}GetProcAddress` originally introduced together with the earliest OpenGL version for exposing extensions (those functions are not part of OpenGL, but the OS support infrastructure required to setup a OpenGL context). Later they got upgraded to a fully featured API access, yet the name stuck (for example the library GLEW, i.e. GL Extension Wrangler, is named for loading extensions, but it loads regular, but later OpenGL version's functionality, that are not extensions per se, as well).

A *extension* is functionality that is not part of a given OpenGL specification, but available in a implementation of said OpenGL specification. Later OpenGL versions may include the extension as it is into the specification. But it's also common that later OpenGL versions make certain changes to a extension on which functionality is based upon.

A good example for extensions having become part of later OpenGL versions without being altered are texture types like GL_TEXTURE_3D or GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP.

> A working example from the hyperlink (OpenGL registry) would help.

You mean how to *use* such an extension?

> How can one write such extensions?

I think you confused something here: It's not the task of the OpenGL user to write such an extension. OpenGL extensions are not a method to add new functionality to a given OpenGL implementation.

It's exactly other way round. A OpenGL implementation that already can do more, than what's contained in the system library and/or the OpenGL specification it is based on, offers its advanced features through extensions.

If you wanted to write your own extension, then because you were a OpenGL driver developer who's task it was to make a super new feature of the latest generation of GPUs available to the users.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, you're right, of course. I'll adjust my wording.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL extensions are basically flags that indicate what a certain GPU is capable of. This knowledge may allow you to leverage that capability although based on your question I would ignore them for now as they're only useful if you want to do something specific.
Also note that relying on a certain extension may exclude a large part of the GPUs that might otherwise run your app without problems.